# AlertView issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, uialertview

I added a UIVIew in AlertView as follow:

```
UIView *alertSubView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 55)];
        [alertSubView addSubview:textField];
        [alertSubView addSubview:charLeftLabel];

        [alert setValue:alertSubView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

**Problem**

```
UIView* alertSubView = [alertView valueForKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

App is crash when I try to get that subview in Alertview Delegate Method.

**It is working fine in iOS7 but there is issue with iOS 8 only**

**Error** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.

Comment: @Fonix, it is working fine in iOS 7 but there is a issue with iOS 8 only

Comment: you need to use custom alert view instead of doing this: check https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Comment: You are trying to access value for alertView while you have set the value for alert against that key

Answer (score 4):

Alert View is deprecated. You should use the `UIAlertController`. This is just a suggestion.

For example as your aspect :

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Controller"
                                      message:@"Alert Message"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 250, 30)];
lbl.text = @"This is a label";
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[viewController.view addSubview:lbl];

UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35, 250, 30)];
tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
tf.placeholder = @"Enter your name";
[viewController.view addSubview:tf];

[alertController setValue:viewController forKey:@"contentViewController"];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                               }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");

                               NSLog(@"Text Value : %@",tf.text);
                           }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this same thing in **swift 2.0** like following code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Controller", message: "Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Cancel",
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (action) in

}

let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in

}

alert.addAction(confirmAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

let VC = UIViewController()
VC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


let lbl =  UILabel()
lbl.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 8, 250, 30)
lbl.text = "this is a label"
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
lbl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
VC.view .addSubview(lbl)


let txt = UITextField()
txt.frame =  CGRectMake(10, 35, 250, 30)
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
txt.placeholder = "enter text"
VC.view .addSubview(txt)


alert.setValue(VC, forKey: "contentViewController")

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Download Demo from Github: https://github.com/nitingohel/NGAlertViewController-Swift2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 55)];
[view addSubview:textField];
[view addSubview:charLeftLabel];
[alert setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but I need to call delegate method for alert view.

Comment: @user2526811 -- which delegate method u need

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 55)];
[view addSubview:textField];
[view addSubview:charLeftLabel];
[alert setValue:view forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Comment: in above give delegate:self then only we call the alertview  delegate method

Comment: you have to set delegate to alertview then only use can the button click and you have not set delegate  to alertview

Comment: I already set Delegate & that's why delegate method is called.

Comment: please read my question carefully & also review others answers.

Comment: in the other code they give delegate=nil that's why suggested you .